# How to find all polygons thats includes special lat long point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, rgeo

I use rgeo and activerecord-postgis-adapter gem. I want to find all records where special point is included in polygon.  I marked rectangular on google map and expect that sql return row if point is inside and does not return row when point is outside. Unfortunately `point_outside_2` also return result. What i am doing wrong? Should I use projections instead of real lat-long?

[image]

```
describe 'polygon' do
  let(:factory) { RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory }

  let(:left_up_corner) { factory.point(50.095073, 19.852121) }
  let(:right_up_corner) { factory.point(50.092230, 20.057740) }
  let(:left_bottom_corner) { factory.point(50.021297, 19.857577) }
  let(:right_bottom_corner) { factory.point(50.015820, 20.051943) }

  let(:point_inside_1) { factory.point(50.059631, 19.939323) }
  let(:point_inside_2) { factory.point(50.029995, 19.941997) }
  let(:point_outside_1) { factory.point(50.153008, 19.990906) }
  let(:point_outside_2) { factory.point(50.118037, 19.970446) }


  let(:line) { factory.line_string([left_up_corner, right_up_corner, right_bottom_corner, left_bottom_corner]) }
  let(:area) { factory.polygon(line) }

  it 'finds nurses with polygon include point' do
    Nurse.create(area: area)
    expect(count_nurses(point_inside_1)).to be 1
    expect(count_nurses(point_inside_2)).to be 1
    expect(count_nurses(point_outside_1)).to be 0
    expect(count_nurses(point_outside_2)).to be 0 # it return 1
  end

  def count_nurses(point)
    Nurse.where("ST_DWithin(area, ST_Point(#{point.coordinates.join(',')}), 4326)").count
  end
end
```

migration:

```
class AddPolygonToNurse < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :nurses, :area, :st_polygon, :geographic => true
    add_column :nurses, :latlong, :st_point, :geographic => true
  end
end
```

Comment: in `ST_Dwithin`, you are asking for point within 4326 meters of the polygon. It should be 0 if you look for point inside the polygon. Also you are using geographic coordinates (lat/long) with a `simple_mercator_factory` which is a projected coordinate system (one of the 2 is wrong, either your coordinates or your factory)

Comment: Yes, I believe he's looking for [ST_Contains](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) rather than `ST_Dwithin`. 4326 is the id for the WGS86 geographic projection system. Point 2 is probably within 4.326 km of the box.

Comment: @JGH This is a correct answer. Thank you very much. I Change 4326 to 0 and now it works.

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge you also have right i wanted to put there id. I also tried to use ST_contains, but i still have a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I'm doing something similar in an app with RGeo to find points within a polygon. Hope this works for you

```
describe 'polygon' do
  let(:factory) { RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory }
  let(:ewkb_generator) do
    RGeo::WKRep::WKBGenerator.new(
      type_format:    :ewkb,
      emit_ewkb_srid: true,
      hex_format:     true
    )
  end

  let(:left_up_corner) { factory.point(50.095073, 19.852121) }
  let(:right_up_corner) { factory.point(50.092230, 20.057740) }
  let(:left_bottom_corner) { factory.point(50.021297, 19.857577) }
  let(:right_bottom_corner) { factory.point(50.015820, 20.051943) }

  let(:point_inside_1) { factory.point(50.059631, 19.939323) }
  let(:point_inside_2) { factory.point(50.029995, 19.941997) }
  let(:point_outside_1) { factory.point(50.153008, 19.990906) }
  let(:point_outside_2) { factory.point(50.118037, 19.970446) }


  let(:line) { factory.line_string([left_up_corner, right_up_corner, right_bottom_corner, left_bottom_corner]) }
  let(:area) { factory.polygon(line) }

  it 'finds nurses with polygon include point' do
    Nurse.create(area: area)
    expect(count_nurses(point_inside_1)).to be 1
    expect(count_nurses(point_inside_2)).to be 1
    expect(count_nurses(point_outside_1)).to be 0
    expect(count_nurses(point_outside_2)).to be 0 # it return 1
  end

  def count_nurses(point)
    ewkb = ewkb_generator.generate(point.projection)
    Nurse.where('ST_Intersects(area, ST_GeomFromEWKB(E?))', "\\\\x#{ewkb}").count
  end
end
```

Comment: It is helpful but it is not direct answer. @JGH solve my problem.  Your solution base on different format of point. Even it is correct I think it is little more complicated